# Existence (non-)homogeneous solutions 1st-order linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation, linear-pde

Assume the following first order linear partial differential equation (PDE):

$$\sum_{i=1}^na_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=1,$$

where the functions $a_i$ are analytic in $x_i$.

**Question 1:**
Is it true that the corresponding homogeneous PDE

$$\sum_{i=1}^na_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=0$$

always has $n-1$ functionally independent solutions $u_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n-1$?

**Question 2:**
Is it true that the original PDE always has a particular solution?

**Remarks:**

- there are no boundary/initial conditions. I am interested in the homogeneous/particular solutions as such.
- I am aware that the solutions, if they exist, are not unique (since they can be combined to new solutions).
- I searched the literature, but I mainly found sources from physics where (i) existence was implicitly assumed, (ii) only specific PDEs where discussed (typically with $n=2$), or (iii) where the discussion focussed on the case where boundary/initial conditions were defined.
- The "best" I could find was the [Cauchy–Kowalevski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Kowalevski_theorem), which however seems too general and which also assumes initial conditions. Also, it only guarantees local existence, and doesn't talk about homogeneous solutions (which makes sense in the nonlinear case).
- If existence cannot be guaranteed in general, I am interested in conditions where this is possible.

Comment: You might like to read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601309/why-does-a-homogeneous-first-order-linear-pde-have-n-1-functionally-independen?rq=1), the only difference seems to be the $1$ vs the $0$ on the RHS of both equations.